# How to start captured current continuations in Racket

Tags: racket, continuations, callcc

I am studying `call/cc` in Racket along the lines of paper *Continuations by example: Exceptions, time-traveling search, generators, threads, and coroutines* [1](http://matt.might.net/articles/programming-with-continuations--exceptions-backtracking-search-threads-generators-coroutines/).

The paper mentions that the most advantageous API is derived from `call/cc` by providing a procedure `lambda (cc) (cc cc)`. I understand this specific `call/cc` invocation returns the current continuation first-class object to the main program.

In the example that follows, the paper calls all this `(right-now)`.

What I see is that inside that same example the `cc` object returned by the abovementioned `call/cc` invocation is always run afterwards by applying it to itself. That's what I don't understand.

I don't see what is so special in `cc` as value, so I have tried to start it as a function with `(cc ())`, or `(cc (lambda () ()))`, or even `(cc "whatever")` and `(cc)`. No joy whatsoever: apparently the continuation wants just *that* application to itself in order to start to run.

Why is that? What is an example that clearly illustrates the uniqueness of running cc's by doing `(cc cc)` ?

Comment: Btw - note that the empty application `()` is an error in Racket. Try something like `(cc 42)`.

Comment: I tried that as well :-( Text is now amended :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
(let ((cc (current-continuation)))
  ...)
```

The continuation of `(current-continuation)` is

```
(lambda (_)
  (let ((cc _))
    ...)
```

Call this continuation `c0`.

The definition of `current-continuation` is:

```
(define (current-continuation)
  (call/cc (lambda (cc) (cc cc))))
```

So `call/cc` calls `(lambda (cc) (cc cc))` with `c0` as argument:

```
  ((lambda (cc) (cc cc)) c0)
= (c0 c0)
```

Inserting the value of c0:

```
((lambda (_)
   (let ((cc _))
     ...)
 c0)
```

which becomes:

```
   (let ((cc c0))
     ...)
```

Which means that inside `...` the identifier `cc` is now bound to the value `c0`.

If  `(c0 42)` occurs in the `...`

The we get:

```
   (c0 42)
= ((lamdba (_)
     (let ((cc _))
      ...)
   42)
= (let ((cc 42))
     ...)
```

And now `cc` is bound to the value 42.

The example uses `(procedure? cc)` and `(future-value? cc)` to test whether `cc` is bound to the continuation (if `(procedure? cc)` is true) and or another value (the future value is here 42).

So in:

```
(define (current-continuation)
  (call/cc (lambda (cc) (cc cc))))
```

the value passed to `(lambda (cc) (cc cc)))` is the continuation. If we want to our hands on it, we need to return it and we do that by passing it to the continuation. I.e.  `(cc something)` will return something, and since we want to get the continuation itself we use `(cc cc)`.

Comment: That's the clue! `(current-continuation) = (call/cc)`. I was overlooking the first pair of parens. Thank you!